# XfiniumPdf - creating PdfDigitalSignature object

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-runtime

I am using XfiniumPdf library, WINRT version.

In my pdf I have field of type PdfSignatureField.

```
    PdfSignatureField signHereField = new PdfSignatureField("signature");
```

I want to set Signature property (type PdfDigitalSignature)

```
    var signature = new Pdf.Core.Security.PdfDigitalSignature();
    // fill signature fields...
    signHereField.Signature = signature;
```

But the problem is I cant create a PdfDigitalSignature object, it says it doesn't contains constructor with 0 arguments (nor 1, 2 etc). 
I have read documentation and it's not mentioned how to create such an object. Visual Studio doesn't give any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Support for digital signatures in Xfinium.Pdf WinRT Edition (and Xamarin iOS and Android, Portable Class Library and other editions) is under development and it will be available during Q1 2016.
At this moment digital signatures are supported only in WinForms and WPF editions of Xfinium.Pdf library.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops Xfinium.Pdf library.